# What do you call a person who is dogmatic in their opinion until someone they see as an authority has an opposing view, and they then flip?

Tags: terminology

I used to think this was actually being dogmatic, but when I actually wrote that the other day I decided to check myself, and it doesn't appear to be the case, however I'm fairly certain there is a word for this behavior, this deference to select authority (e.g. someone doesn't believe in climate change regardless of the scientific consensus but then some radio personality he/she listens to starts espousing the danger and suddenly the person then believes in climate change).

Comment: I would say they're lapdogmatic.

Comment: Well that's funny at least!  Perhaps we should add that to the urban dictionary in hopes it's adopted by Webster?

Comment: What, it's isn't in Webster's?  Then surely is must be in Oxford!

Comment: Sounds like a *whim of iron*.

Comment: There should be a groan-vote for atrocities like Hot Licks'. The currect answer is that they're turning tail.

Comment: Not sure about a noun for it, but there's a related logical fallacy if they use this as the basis for an argument: ***appeal to authority***.

Comment: Technically, [tag:single-word-requests] require an exemplary context to allow us to know which kinds of word is the best suited for the application. Would you please add one? It'd help us to determine if you're looking for an adjective or a noun.

Answer (score 1):

capricious - subject to, led by, or indicative of a sudden, odd notion or unpredictable change; erratic:

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/capricious

You could say that the individual shows a capricious discipline in the face of authority.

Answer (score 0):

If the authority figure is a sophisticated user of mass media, then the scapegrace is succumbing to a **cult of personality**. The authority figure is an expert at getting people to **roll over**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cult_of_personality

But this puts the onus on the authority figure.

If you want to place the fault squarely on the one changing allegiance, then they are a **spineless** jellyfish.

> Spineless, 2. lacking resolution; weak and purposeless.

Google: spineless

Answer (score 0):

That's a fox in a boar's clothing.

It's a play on the old idiom about wolves and sheep.  In politics those who never flip flop are boars.  Those who do are foxes.  Being a fox allows you flexibility.  But being known as a fox will lose you votes from both sides.  So smart foxes pretend to be boars.  For as long as they can.

Comment: Or a sheep in wolves' clothing?

Answer (score 0):

I would call such a man "POTENTIAL CONVERT". Men do change in situations like these when they abandon their age-old cherished views or dogmatic notions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking about a *loyal follower*, as in "He is a *loyal follower* of Smith, whose opinion rests solely on what Smith has to say about the topic."

You might prefer the adjective *mindless*, which implies someone who doesn't consider a position before adopting it. E.g. "Smith's *mindless followers* espouse whatever opinion he offers, regardless of its logical fallacies or salacious nature."

Answer (score 0):

The problem with many responses here is that they are loaded terms. This is ironic in the context of an inquiry about dogmatism. A neutral term would be acolyte or disciple. They are not necessarily pejorative terms, even though one might conclude that being an acolyte or disciple is not healthy.